# ParametricNDSolveValue with SparseArrays

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, sparse-arrays

I want to solve large, sparse matrix systems with ParametricNDSolveValue and was hoping to use SparseArray to speed up the computation. However I find that ParametricNDSolveValue doesn't seem to work when I use a SparseArray instead of a normal matrix.

Here is a minimal example:

```
m1[t_] = KroneckerProduct[{t, 0, 0}, {0, t, 0}];
m2[t_] = SparseArray[m1[t]];
m0 = IdentityMatrix[Length[m1[0]]];

test1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[t] == m1[t - t1], f[0] == m0}, 
  f[1], {t, 0, 1}, {t1}];
test2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[t] == m2[t - t1], f[0] == m0}, 
  f[1], {t, 0, 1}, {t1}];

test1[1]
test2[1]
```

> {{1., 0.333333, 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}
>
> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

If I change `t_` to `t_?NumericQ` in the definitions of `m1` and `m2` nothing changes.

So my question is

1. Is it possible to get ParametricNDSolveValue to work with SparseArrays
2. Is there a better way of approaching this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `test1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[t] == m1[t - t1].f[t], f[0] == m0},
    f[1], {t, 0, 1}, {t1}];
test2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[t] == m2[t - t1].f[t], f[0] == m0},
    f[1], {t, 0, 1}, {t1}];`

Comment: You're right that my example with NDSolve defines a different equation than the example with ParametricNDSolveValue (specifically the `.f[t]`) part. If I remove the `.f[t]` from the NDSolve it also breaks with a sparse array.

Following your idea, I just use `.IdentityMatrix[size]` and it works! Thank you for your comment!

If you want to write it up quickly, I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, looking closer at it, this really doesn't use sparse arrays at all. When I do `.IdentityMatrix` this effectively just converts my spare array back into a normal matrix and I can reap no benefit from having a sparse array.

Most of my matrix elements are 0 and it is a waste of time for Mathematica to numerically solve $f_{i,j}'(t)=0, \ f_{i,j}(0)=0$ for thousands of pairs of $i,j$. I am trying to get around this without manually breaking my equations down into components.

Comment: Use `test2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[t] == Normal[m2[t - t1]], 
   f[0] == m0}, f[1], {t, 0, 1}, {t1}]`

Comment: Please see my previous comment. Using `Normal` completely removes any benefit I hope to get from using sparse arrays

Comment: Your sparse arrays are much too dense (because to low dimensional) to provide any performance improvements.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher these are just simple examples to illustrate the issue. My actual code has 64x64 matrices with < 300 nonzero elements